# Create multiple output tables from one query

Tags: postgresql

I'm an inexperienced Postgres user and need help if someone can suggest it.

I require output tables of column 'county' so all counties in the table have their own table. I need independent tables for each to use separately. My source table is 'my_counties' and 'county' contains the variable county names I wish to separate.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction()
RETURNS SETOF my_counties AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    county my_counties%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

    FOR row in SELECT county DISTINCT my_counties LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT * INTO myschema.test_' || row.county || ' from myschema.source WHERE source.county = ' || row.county;
    END LOOP;

RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The error I return is

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"

Comment: Maybe it should be `SELECT DISTINCT county FROM my_counties`

Comment: Unrelated, but: The non-standard `select into new_table` should be replaced with the standard compliant `create table as select...`

Comment: But why do you want to de-normalize something that sounds like a properly normalized table? Why do you "require" this? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Also: your function does not return anything, so you should define it as `returns void`

Comment: I will be supplying each county table to each individual county organisation. What do you mean by “returns void”? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'm an inexperienced Postgres user and need help if someone can suggest it.

A few things, this is a bad idea, you probably want [Table Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html) because essentially you're creating partitions of another table.

If you don't want to partition a table, you probably want a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) which sits as a table on the disk, but it can be refreshed from the query which is was created from with a simple command `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

What I think you want is something like this,

```
SELECT FORMAT ($$
  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW %I.%I AS
    SELECT *
    FROM my_countries
    WHERE country = %L;
  $$,
  'myschema',
  'test_' || country,
  country
)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT county
  FROM my_counties
) AS t(country);
```

Run that in `psql` and then run `\gexec`, or loop through that result set and run `EXECUTE` in plpgsql.